# How to assemble a Regular Expression the includes newlines and stop at particular character sequence?

Tags: java, regex, extract

I am writing some regular expr to extract sentences from text.. My problem is that my expression getting unwanted texts also...

**For Example :**

The main Text-

```
1)
.......
.......
 Inventors: Peng Ji, Beijing (CN); Lin Luo, Beijing 
(CN); Vugranam C. Sreedhar, 
Yorktown Heights, NY (US); Shun 
Xiang Yang, Beijing (CN); Yu Zhang, 
Beijing (CN) 
(73) Assignee: International Business Machines 
Corporation, Armonk, NY (US) 
........
........


2)
.......
.......
(75) Inventors: Satoru Katsurayama, Tokyo (JP); 
Tomoe Yamashiro, Tokyo (JP); Takashi 
Hirano, Tokyo (JP) 
(73) Assignee: Sumitomo Bakelite Co., Ltd., Tokyo 
(JP) 
.......
........
```

I want to extract like below (Expected Output) :

```
(75) Inventors: Satoru Katsurayama, Tokyo (JP); 
Tomoe Yamashiro, Tokyo (JP); Takashi 
Hirano, Tokyo (JP) 

(75) Inventors: Satoru Katsurayama, Tokyo (JP); 
Tomoe Yamashiro, Tokyo (JP); Takashi 
Hirano, Tokyo (JP)
```

**My Works and Research :**

So I build a Regex like this :

### (?s).\s*Inventor\w*:\s*\w*([\w\d,.\s)(-]+);([\w\s\r.\',();]+)

**Problem I got :**

But my regex is return output like this

```
 Inventors: Peng Ji, Beijing (CN); Lin Luo, Beijing 
(CN); Vugranam C. Sreedhar, 
Yorktown Heights, NY (US); Shun 
Xiang Yang, Beijing (CN); Yu Zhang, 
Beijing (CN) 
(73) Assignee


Inventors: Satoru Katsurayama, Tokyo (JP); 
Tomoe Yamashiro, Tokyo (JP); Takashi 
Hirano, Tokyo (JP) 
(73) Assignee
```

That is the **(73) Assignee** also parsed in by my expression but i don't need it .. I tried much but can't recify my problem.

**My efforts:** 
I also tried NOT ^ operator but  I not worked.. Since I am new to regex , I can't go up much .

Please guide me to remove the **(73) Assignee** from being parsed ..

Comment: Will the next line *always* be `(73) Assignee:`? Or will it sometimes be something else? Will it at least always contain the phrase `Assignee:`?

Comment: Yes. It always .. It always contains that @Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead after your regex.

Your final regex (with some improvement) would look like this:

```
(?s)\(75\)\s+Inventor\w*:\s*\w*([\w\d,.\s)(-]+);([\w\s.\',();]+)(?=\(73\)\s+Assignee:)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank u very much. I worked.. Since I no reps I unable to upvote. Sorry for that....  Thank u once again